# Read More after x numberof characters JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i want to show only 300 characters-long paragraph, below is the code im using to hide/show the full text, what should i do to make it show only 300 characters and then show full text when user clicks "show more" button?

**TPL file:**

```
<div id="tab-description">
<div id="more-1" class="fulltext">
<p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
</div>
<button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="more-1" class="toggle-content" hidden><span class="text">Show more</span></button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
if ('querySelector' in document && 
'addEventListener' in window) {

var toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-content');
var fullTextWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.fulltext');
var fullText;
var toggleButtonText;


[].forEach.call(fullTextWrappers, function(fullTextWrapper) {
    // hide all full text on load
    fullTextWrapper.setAttribute('hidden', true);
});

[].forEach.call(toggleButtons, function(toggleButton) {
    // show toggle more buttons
    toggleButton.removeAttribute('hidden');

    // add listener for each button
    toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function () {

        fullTextWrapper = this.parentElement.querySelector('.fulltext');
        toggleButtonText = this.querySelector('.text');

        // change attributes and text if full text is shown/hidden
        if (!fullTextWrapper.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
            toggleButtonText.innerText = 'Show More';
            fullTextWrapper.setAttribute('hidden', true);
            toggleButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
        } else {
            toggleButtonText.innerText = 'Show Less';
            fullTextWrapper.removeAttribute('hidden');
            toggleButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
        }
});
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is split on each letter and then splice the first 300 items out.

```
let para = p.textContent.split('')
let first300 = para.splice(0, 300)
```

Here is a basic usage example:

```js
// Get the div content
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).forEach(div => {
  let para = div.textContent.split('')
  let first300 = para.splice(0, 300)

  div.innerHTML = `<p>${first300.join('')}<span class="hidden">${para.join('')}</span></p><p><a href="" class="more">Show More/Less...</a></p>`

  div.querySelector('.more').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.closest('div').querySelector('p span:last-child').classList.toggle('hidden')
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fermentum dui odio, et gravida felis ultricies in. Etiam rutrum eros eget vulputate eleifend. Donec dictum, lectus sit amet dictum porta, tortor nisi rhoncus velit, sit amet viverra massa dolor vitae quam. Aliquam interdum purus sed rutrum mattis. Phasellus enim massa, placerat sed porttitor ac, porta in lacus. Etiam vehicula maximus blandit. Donec gravida est ut leo cursus sagittis. Sed tempus maximus aliquet. Mauris tempus magna lacus. Maecenas id nunc sem. Cras feugiat nunc in nibh consequat, at blandit erat sagittis. Nam rhoncus fringilla ante eget consectetur. Morbi volutpat, arcu ut ultrices posuere, ipsum neque mattis mi, non eleifend mi mi in nunc. Nullam sodales gravida orci a imperdiet. Donec facilisis rutrum pharetra. Fusce efficitur erat sed aliquam lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nisl eros, finibus vitae congue ac, rhoncus non enim. Sed interdum vehicula luctus. Nam lorem velit, feugiat at nunc sed, luctus dignissim lacus. Cras risus lorem, ornare nec mauris eu, scelerisque tincidunt mauris. Donec ac accumsan diam, at molestie turpis. Nam nec placerat orci. In sem libero, egestas nec magna id, scelerisque consectetur mauris. Sed finibus faucibus mauris eget vestibulum. Aenean nec odio viverra, euismod sem sed, interdum ante. Donec sit amet mauris et lacus ultrices feugiat suscipit in lectus. Aliquam fermentum euismod tellus, sed volutpat velit luctus id. In quis tortor odio. Cras tincidunt, nisi ut fringilla euismod, tortor arcu placerat sem, et dignissim sem quam eu enim. Duis vitae ante in erat dapibus malesuada.</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fermentum dui odio, et gravida felis ultricies in. Etiam rutrum eros eget vulputate eleifend. Donec dictum, lectus sit amet dictum porta, tortor nisi rhoncus velit, sit amet viverra massa dolor vitae quam. Aliquam interdum purus sed rutrum mattis. Phasellus enim massa, placerat sed porttitor ac, porta in lacus. Etiam vehicula maximus blandit. Donec gravida est ut leo cursus sagittis. Sed tempus maximus aliquet. Mauris tempus magna lacus. Maecenas id nunc sem. Cras feugiat nunc in nibh consequat, at blandit erat sagittis. Nam rhoncus fringilla ante eget consectetur. Morbi volutpat, arcu ut ultrices posuere, ipsum neque mattis mi, non eleifend mi mi in nunc. Nullam sodales gravida orci a imperdiet. Donec facilisis rutrum pharetra. Fusce efficitur erat sed aliquam lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nisl eros, finibus vitae congue ac, rhoncus non enim. Sed interdum vehicula luctus. Nam lorem velit, feugiat at nunc sed, luctus dignissim lacus. Cras risus lorem, ornare nec mauris eu, scelerisque tincidunt mauris. Donec ac accumsan diam, at molestie turpis. Nam nec placerat orci. In sem libero, egestas nec magna id, scelerisque consectetur mauris. Sed finibus faucibus mauris eget vestibulum. Aenean nec odio viverra, euismod sem sed, interdum ante. Donec sit amet mauris et lacus ultrices feugiat suscipit in lectus. Aliquam fermentum euismod tellus, sed volutpat velit luctus id. In quis tortor odio. Cras tincidunt, nisi ut fringilla euismod, tortor arcu placerat sem, et dignissim sem quam eu enim. Duis vitae ante in erat dapibus malesuada.</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fermentum dui odio, et gravida felis ultricies in. Etiam rutrum eros eget vulputate eleifend. Donec dictum, lectus sit amet dictum porta, tortor nisi rhoncus velit, sit amet viverra massa dolor vitae quam. Aliquam interdum purus sed rutrum mattis. Phasellus enim massa, placerat sed porttitor ac, porta in lacus. Etiam vehicula maximus blandit. Donec gravida est ut leo cursus sagittis. Sed tempus maximus aliquet. Mauris tempus magna lacus. Maecenas id nunc sem. Cras feugiat nunc in nibh consequat, at blandit erat sagittis. Nam rhoncus fringilla ante eget consectetur. Morbi volutpat, arcu ut ultrices posuere, ipsum neque mattis mi, non eleifend mi mi in nunc. Nullam sodales gravida orci a imperdiet. Donec facilisis rutrum pharetra. Fusce efficitur erat sed aliquam lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nisl eros, finibus vitae congue ac, rhoncus non enim. Sed interdum vehicula luctus. Nam lorem velit, feugiat at nunc sed, luctus dignissim lacus. Cras risus lorem, ornare nec mauris eu, scelerisque tincidunt mauris. Donec ac accumsan diam, at molestie turpis. Nam nec placerat orci. In sem libero, egestas nec magna id, scelerisque consectetur mauris. Sed finibus faucibus mauris eget vestibulum. Aenean nec odio viverra, euismod sem sed, interdum ante. Donec sit amet mauris et lacus ultrices feugiat suscipit in lectus. Aliquam fermentum euismod tellus, sed volutpat velit luctus id. In quis tortor odio. Cras tincidunt, nisi ut fringilla euismod, tortor arcu placerat sem, et dignissim sem quam eu enim. Duis vitae ante in erat dapibus malesuada.</div>
```

Comment: Thiis works with all the divs in the website, pardon my amateurish/silly question but, what if i want to get de div content from just one especific div id or class?

Comment: Just change `querySelectorAll('div')` to `querySelectorAll('.my-class')` or `querySelectorAll('#my-id')`

Comment: It worked! now the only thing is that for some reason all the paragraphs of the text are join together leaving no white spaces, i' thinking removing the ".join"  in        div.innerHTML = `<p>${first600.join('')}<span class="hidden">${para.join('')}</span></p><p><a href="" class="more">Leer Mas/Menos...</a></p>

Comment: You could add margin to the bottom of the divs

Comment: tried adding margin to div bottom and to <p> bottom, didn't work either way :(

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```js
var desc = "";
document.getElementById("showText").onclick = showText;

function showText() {
  document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = desc; 
}

function minifyText(len) {
  var textElem = document.getElementById("desc");
  desc = textElem.innerHTML;
  textElem.innerHTML = desc.substring(0, len) +"...";  
}

minifyText(11); // Shorten the text when page loads
```

```html
<p id="desc">This is some text, for example your description</p>
<button id="showText">Show text</button>
```

Comment: Thank's bro, tryed but no luck. It occurs to maybe has something to do with the fact that the text inside <p> </p> tags, is a variable that i have to call <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>